# How can I change the + icon position when using material table editable feature

Tags: material-ui, google-material-icons, material-table

In material-table row can be added by clicking on + icon on top right corner. I want to replace that icon at the bottom of the screen as a button "ADD". But material-table accept the icon object and there is not other prop to do it. Is there any way I can do it? I am using material-table editable feature https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable